# DataGridComboBoxColumn set value from DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="RateTable"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RateTableDataView}"
              Margin="20"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Width="725">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate Table" 
                                Width="75" 
                                Binding="{Binding RateTable}" 
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" 
                                IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Match Type" 
                                    Width="100" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MatchTypeCollection}}"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedMatchType}" 
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MatchType}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="EARNDED" 
                                    Width="100" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EARNDEDCollection}}"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EARNDED}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

This works as expected EXCEPT that the values for the combo boxes are not being set to what they are in the ItemSource.

For instance, the data I am getting back from SQL and placing in `RateTableDataView` has EARNDED set to 'D2000' but when the table is displayed the values in the combo boxes are blank.

How do I initialize the combo box with the value from `RateTableDataView`?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for EARNDED

In ViewModel I create an ObservableCollection of EARNDED values:

```
    public ObservableCollection<String> EARNDEDComboBoxValues
    {
        get
        {
            DataSet _dataset = new DataSet("TempDataSet");

            // Get reference to DelphiaConfigInfo
            DelphiaConfigModel _config =
                (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).SystemSetupViewModel.DelphiaConfigInfo;

            using (SQLClass _sql = new SQLClass(_config.DatabaseInfo))
            {
                using (SqlConnection _conn = _sql.Connection)
                {
                    SqlCommand _cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
                    _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    _cmd.CommandText = "select EARNDED from [dbo].[UPDTLM]";

                    SqlDataAdapter _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

                    _adapter.Fill(_dataset);
                }
            }

            // Get List of 'MatchType' values using Linq
            List<String> _values =
                _dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .Select(datarow => datarow.Field<String>("EARNDED")).ToList<String>();

            // Convert List to ObservableCollection 
            return new ObservableCollection<String>(_values);
        }
    }
```

And in the XAML I cerate a static resource to the EARNDEDComboBoxValues (apparently DataGRidComboBoxColumn cannot bind to a non-static property):

```
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="EARNDEDCollection"
                              Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.EARNDEDComboBoxValues}" />
```

The combo boxes are being populated with data which does appear when I open the combo box but the initial value, as retrieved from SQL, is not set in the combo box.  The combo box is blank (nothing is selected).

Comment: Can you please show your EARNDEDCollection code or xaml.

Comment: When you say they aren't being set to you mean nothing is selected or the combo box isn't being populated?

Comment: @ethicallogics see edits

Comment: Have you tried it by binding "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.EARNDEDComboBoxValues}" directly to ComboBoxColumn ItemsSource ?

Comment: @ethicallogics doing that breaks the combo box, the drop down has no values in it.  I found that by setting the property SelectedItemBinding={Binding MatchType} correctly displays the intial value.  Still not working on EARNDED which is odd as both are simple string values.

Comment: all what i can is guess . Create one DataGridTemplateColumn and add combobox to it and set same itemsource and see if it gets populated.

Comment: It turned out that the values from SQL used to populate EARNDED had a trailing space.  I added .Trim() to the Linq statement and it now works.  Thanks for your help.